# How do you log out with DRF Djoser JWT?

Tags: django-rest-framework, djoser

This is quite a simple question when I'm using JWT based authentication and there's seems to be no url that I can make a request to, if I want to logout. Is it practical to just simply clear the `localStorage` and refresh the page unlike token based authentication where you need to make a request to `/token/logout/` ?